# detect CAShapeLayer touch

Tags: ios

I have created a spider chart by overiding draw rect, I am using core grahics CAShapeLayer to draw my areas, there are multiple CAShapeLayer regions which are created on the screen, I want to detect which layer is touched  when the users touches... but I can't figure out how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, you should not be drawing layers in drawRect, but that is not your question.  To identify a layer that is "touched" you can do something like this...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        for (id sublayer in self.view.layer.sublayers) {
            BOOL touchInLayer = NO;
            if ([sublayer isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]]) {
                CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = sublayer;
                if (CGPathContainsPoint(shapeLayer.path, 0, touchLocation, YES)) {
                    // This touch is in this shape layer
                    touchInLayer = YES;
                }
            } else {
                CALayer *layer = sublayer;
                if (CGRectContainsPoint(layer.frame, touchLocation)) {
                    // Touch is in this rectangular layer
                    touchInLayer = YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jody, can you just expand the code inside the if condition for more light,

Comment: OK, I updated it with a little more detail.  Basically, if it is a shape layer, you query its path and see if that path contains the point...  Note, though, that you have to pass the fill-type as part of the CGPathContainsPoint - I assumed even/odd.  Use whatever you need...

Comment: This doesn't work for touches on the border if the line width is greater than 1.

Comment: To take into any `.transform`s in the layer heirarchy convert the point to the layer that has the path as its `layer.path` i.e. (Swift) `let p = viewLayer.convertPoint(touchLocation, toLayer: sublayer)`.

Answer (score 0):

For swift answer
This is beginTracking as the touch starts, you can also implement continueTracking in case you what to keep tracking.

How it works, you get the touch location inside the beginTracking and check, your layer frames contains the point you touch if yes it will print the statement. Same way you can check for all your layer

```
override open func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
     let loaction = touch.location(in: self)
     //update yourLayer with your layer name
     if yourLayer.frame.contains(previousLoaction) { 
        Print("Touch is inside yourLayer layer")
     }
}
```