# iOS method containsPoint is not working

Tags: ios

I have a view like this:

```
// .h file
@interface LayerBubbleView : UIView

/**
 *  click handler
 */
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^clickHandler)(NSString* identifier, CAShapeLayer* layer);

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withDataArray:(NSArray *)dataArray;

@end

// .m file
#import "BDPLayerBubbleView.h"

@interface BDPLayerBubbleView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *paths;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *identifiers;

@end

@implementation BDPLayerBubbleView

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withDataArray:(NSArray *)dataArray {
    self = [self initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        _paths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _identifiers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.count; i++) {
            NSArray *data = dataArray[i];
            CGRect frame = [data[0] CGRectValue]; // please ignore here, just for demo
            CGFloat radius = [data[1] doubleValue];
            CGPoint center = [data[2] CGPointValue];
            UIColor *fillColor = data[3];
            UIColor *borderColor = data[4];
            NSString *identifier = data[5];

            CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
            UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame cornerRadius:radius];
            [_paths addObject:bezierPath];
            [_identifiers addObject:identifier];
            shapeLayer.path = [bezierPath CGPath];
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = [borderColor CGColor];
            shapeLayer.fillColor = [fillColor CGColor];
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.5;
            shapeLayer.bounds = frame;
            shapeLayer.position = center;
            [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Touch handling

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    for(int i=0;i<[_paths count];i++) {
        UIBezierPath* path = _paths[i];
        CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = self.layer.sublayers[i];
        if ([path containsPoint:touchPoint] || [shapeLayer containsPoint:touchPoint])
        {
            NSString *identifier = _identifiers[i];

            if([self.layer.sublayers[i] isKindOfClass:CAShapeLayer.class] && [identifier length] > 0) {
                CAShapeLayer* l = self.layer.sublayers[i];

                if(_clickHandler) {
                    _clickHandler(identifier, l);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The logic is, there are lots of bubble layers on the view, and when user taps on the bubble, I can detect which bubble layer user taps, so I can trigger the corresponding clickHandler and highlight the bubble layer.

However, neither `[path containsPoint:touchPoint]` nor `[shapeLayer containsPoint:touchPoint]` return YES for all the sub layers. I am not sure what's wrong with my code?

So I was suggest to use `CGPathContainsPoint` and `CGRectContainsPoint` to detect. I tested, `CGPathContainsPoint` DOES NOT work while `CGRectContainsPoint`DID work.

I am now confused the differences among the CG APIs and the UIKit wrapped APIs. Could any expert to explain? I still hope `containsPoint` can work.

Comment: Your `dataArray` should contain a list of custom objects.  Doing things like `[data[1] doubleValue]` is tedious and error-prone.

Comment: This is a demo code, so it is meaningless to talk about this here

Comment: The code I posted here for the question

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint) `if (CGRectContainsPoint(shapeLayer.frame,touchPoint))` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect CAShapeLayer touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155108/detect-cashapelayer-touch)

Comment: well, I tested `CGPathContainsPoint(shapeLayer.path, 0, touchPoint, YES)`, not working, but `CGRectContainsPoint(shapeLayer.frame, touchPoint)` is working. Could someone explain? I am quite confused, about these CG APIs and the Objective-C APIs

Comment: @Wezly I think I still need explaination about these APIs. So I have edit the question, and please reopen it, not dup

Comment: I possibly find out the reason, each layer only contains one path, I found my path's origin point is always (0,0), while the corresponding layer has a valid origin point. However, I am not clear, what's the relation with path and layer, especially the origin point, anchorPoint, position